# 502 Bad gateway error for ASP.NET core react app when is accessed thru the azure Application gateway

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core, react-router, azure-application-gateway

I have an ASP.NET core React app deployed on the Azure App service and this is a private endpoint, We can access the application only thru the Azure Application gateway URL.

Backend app URL: https://example.com
Application gateway URL: https://my-domain-name/my-base-path

When I access the application thru the application gateway URL I get 502 Bad gateway errors for static CSS and js files such as bundle.js and chunk.js of the React

Comment: What does the backend heath probe show for your backend pool? If the backend health is down Azure Application gateway won't even try to route any traffic to the backend pool (reporting a 502 Bad Gateway error) until the backend health issue is resolved,

Comment: It is showing as healthy.

Comment: Can you detail the config of your Rules, Listeners and Rewrites in App Gateway? The part in your question where you have a different Backend App URL to the App Gateway URL seems like it wouldn't work without a correctly configured Rewrite. 

The 502 error you describe is absolutely from App Gateway, not you App/Server. Given that the backend pool is healthy, the only logical conclusion I can draw is an issue with Listener/Rules/Rewrites.

Comment: Also, have you been through troubleshooting steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#overview